# How to install a pip package locally in Dockerfile?

Tags: git, github, docker, pip

I'm trying to clone a python package from github and then install it locally with `pip -e` as follows:

```
RUN git clone https://github.com/st4lk/django-rest-social-auth.git
RUN pip install -e django-rest-social-auth
```

but I get error message:

```
Step 6 : RUN pip install -e django-rest-social-auth
 ---> Running in 8943e688573f
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 356, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2476, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2190, in load
    ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 25, in <module>
    from requests.compat import IncompleteRead
ImportError: cannot import name IncompleteRead
```

What's wrong?

---

Full `Dockerfile` for reference:

```
FROM debian:jessie

ADD . /workflows

# Install dependencies

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    python-django \
    python-psycopg2 \
    python-django-celery \
    rabbitmq-server \
    python-django-jsonfield \
    python-pip

RUN pip install djangorestframework \
    python-social-auth

RUN git clone https://github.com/st4lk/django-rest-social-auth.git

RUN pip install -e django-rest-social-auth

# Get everything ready and run

RUN python /workflows/manage.py validate
RUN python /workflows/manage.py collectstatic --noinput

CMD python /workflows/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `IncompleteRead` name was removed from `requests.compat` in https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/commit/47d0517d66e8cf5832768262221f0357ae134ad1.

After completing this section of your Dockerfile...

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    python-django \
    python-psycopg2 \
    python-django-celery \
    rabbitmq-server \
    python-django-jsonfield \
    python-pip
```

You have Requests version 2.4.3 and pip 1.5.6.  Both of these are quite old.  When you next run `pip install`...

```
RUN pip install djangorestframework \
    python-social-auth
```

...this upgrades your Requests package to 2.9.1, which is no longer compatible with the old version of `pip` installed in your image.

You can avoid this problem by installing a newer version of `pip`.
Rather than installing the `python-pip` package, just use
`easy_install` to acquire `pip`:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    python-django \
    python-psycopg2 \
    python-django-celery \
    rabbitmq-server \
    python-django-jsonfield

RUN easy_install pip
```

This will install the latest version of `pip`, which will operate successfully with the version of Requests installed required by your subsequent Python module installs.

Comment: Thank you, larsks, I followed your suggestion and build works now.